# Hyper-V NIC Teaming - Host *AND* VM

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012, network-teaming

All:

In a Server 2012 R2 environment, would there be any advantage of teaming vNIC's inside (max team size is 2 I believe?) a WS2012R2 Hyper-V VM when the VM is connected to a vSwitch comprised of a host NIC team of all 4 1Gbps NIC ports on the physical NIC card?   The vNICs in the VM's report 10GbE but ultimately would be limited by the VMBus for intra server VM communications, and the host NIC team for external network communications. So I am not seeing the benefit of the VM team.  What am I overlooking?

/rw

Comment: A virtual machine NIC team must have each team member connected to a different virtual switch. It doesn't sound like that's what you're talking about.

Comment: Oh. yeah.  that's an interesting point - that alone help justify a NIC team within a VM.  Otherwise if it was tied to just a single vSW, there would be little value.  thanks for responding !